# How to write Indic text in Konsole?

Tags: linux, unicode, kubuntu, konsole

In this thread, entitled **[Terminal with support for Indic characters](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/11/msg01482.html)**, someone laments the difficulty of displaying Indic characters (outputting Malyalam text like "അഖിൽ കൃഷ്ണൻ എസ്"), to which someone replied (excerpted):

> Since gnome-terminal & its emulators like guake uses vtk which do not provide complex utf-8 rendering, Indic Language support is poor in them.
>
> Konsole of KDE & its frameworks like yakuake works well on Indic Languages.

However, the thread doesn't explain how to actually implement it with Konsole.

I have installed Indic fonts and have UTF8 support.  Text seems to render correctly when pasted. My issue is in inputting the text. I suspect that Konsole (and other terminal emulators) may not play nice with IBus.

What could I be missing since this is supposed to work?

Comment: As pointed in email thread, You need to have indic fonts installed and utf8 support for them as well.

Comment: And an appropriate keyboard layout or IME.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus, how about posting an answer (including how having "utf8 support" translates to "how to have utf8 support)?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, I apologize for editing question that way, should have included that excerpt. Will be more careful in future edits. Also I just pointed to what was in the email thread and really have no idea how to write Indic texts in konsole.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus I have done all that. Text seems to render correctly when pasted. My issue is in inputting the text. I think that Konsole (and other terminal emulators) doesn't play nice with IBus.

Comment: New Information: Recently, another terminal emulator [Link](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/1468)  project seems to be working on a related issue right now. [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50552). This means that soon this functionality may be available in other emulators.